# Track clicks on Flash button in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, flash, goal-tracking, universal-analytics

Client is having a GoogleVoice's "*Call me*" button on their website and I'm trying to figure out how to set up a tracking for clicks on it as it's not standard link but Flash.

**Button** (*for those not familiar with it*):

[image]

I tried Googling for way to achieve this but couldn't find proper instructions.
Can somebody shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1):

I found a question on Stack Overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444562/javascript-onclick-event-over-flash-object) related to using JavaScript to track Flash objects.

It's best if you use *onmousedown()* like this:

```
<div onmousedown="clickBanner(1)">
<object>
<param name="movie" value="3.swf">
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
<embed wmode=transparent allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" src="3.swf">
</embed>
</object>
</div>
```